# Facebook Game Application Flash CS6 AS3.0

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript, facebook-as3-api

I'm planning on creative a Facebook app for a college project but I'm unsure as to how to go about specifics.

I have been working within flash (animation, general AS3.0 coding) for close to three years so I'm pretty comfortable working within this program. I have looked up a lot of information about using the Facebook SDK for ActionScript etc. but I'm really not sure what I'm doing in relation to this.

Is it possible to create an entire game within Flash CS6 and then add any necessary PHP additions (for posting to timelines etc.) afterwards?

Sorry for not having a clue but any help would be extremely welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can get some examples from

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Thanks
Dhiraj

Comment: Thanks, already been there and it had confused me profusely, maybe I should just take things step by step!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to post data from the game to Facebook - for example, a simple "I scored [score] points!" message on the user's wall - then you should not need to write any code outside of your Flash game, other than making sure that the page it's on is set up correctly (with Facebook tags and JavaScript, etc.).

I found this post helpful in showing the basics of using the AS3 API to log in and pull data from Facebook into Flash: http://permadi.com/blog/2011/02/using-facebook-graph-api-in-flash-as3-1-5/.

Comment: Thanks :) Also, do you know if it always has to be linked with JS? Or can PHP be used instead?

Comment: The AS3 API uses JavaScript as a bridge to communicate with Facebook, so the containing page must contain the correct JavaScript files for it to work.